# Is there a standard DSN format?

Tags: php, pdo

PHP PDO uses this style:

**MySQL**

`mysql:host=hostname;dbname=databasename` with username and password in their own separate parameters

**PostgreSQL**

`pgsql:host=hostname;dbname=databasename;user=username;password=password`

But then when search Github for a DSN parser, they seem to use a different format altogether, like this:

`mysql://user:pass@hostname:port/databasename`

My question is, is there actually a standard DSN format that every language accepts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's see what is actually **DSN**?

**DSN** stands for **Data Source Name**. But this is also known as **Database Source Name**. `DSN` term also overlaps with **connection string**. Most systems do not make a distinction between `DSNs` or `connection strings` and the term can often be used interchangeably.

DSN attributes may include, but are not limited to:

1. the name of the data source
2. the location of the data source
3. the name of a database driver which can access the data source
4. a user ID for data access (if required)
5. a user password for data access (if required)

The information is above taken from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_source_name)

In general, the following format of a **connection string** is maintained by many languages for database connections. This may be a community standard. But I didn't see any specification of `DSN`.

```
scheme://username:password@host:port/dbname?param1=value1&param2=value2&...
```

There are several ways to connect to a database. So there are some common attributes that are used for all types of database connections. See the following examples:

**Connect to database through a socket**

```
mysql://user@unix(/path/to/socket)/dbname
```

**Connect to database on a non standard port**

```
pgsql://user:pass@tcp(localhost:5555)/dbname
```

**Connect to SQLite on a Unix machine using options**

```
sqlite:////full/unix/path/to/file.db?mode=0666
```

**Connect to SQLite on a Windows machine using options**

```
sqlite:///c:/full/windows/path/to/file.db?mode=0666
```

**Connect to MySQLi using SSL**

```
mysqli://user:pass@localhost/pear?key=client-key.pem&cert=client-cert.pem
```

**Connecting to MS Access sometimes requires admin as the user name**

```
odbc(access)://admin@/datasourcename
```

**Connecting to ODBC with a specific cursor**

```
odbc(access)://admin@/datasourcename?cursor=SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC
```

Here I am providing two links for PostgreSQL and MySQL respectively. You will find there how they use `connection string` to connect a database.

- [Connect PostgreSQL using connection string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING)
- [Connect MySQL using connection string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting-using-uri-or-key-value-pairs.html)